# Possible to change the original variables in an array?

Tags: python, arrays

Consider this (uncontroversial) simple example:

```python
allvars = []
a = 1
allvars.append(a)
b = 2
allvars.append(b)
c = 3
allvars.append(c)
d = 4
allvars.append(d)
e = 5
allvars.append(e)

for ix in allvars:
  ix = ix + 1 # changes local variable ix, but not array elements
print(allvars) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i, ix in enumerate(allvars):
  allvars[i] = ix + 1 # changes array elements ...
print(allvars) # [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

# ... but not original variables
print(a,b,c,d,e) # 1 2 3 4 5
```

Even if we had some variables "stored" into a Python list - changing that list did not change the original variables.

It is clear why this happens, if we recall that Python in fact stores pointers (as I read somewhere, "python has names, not variables"):

- when we do `a = 1`; `a` points to the address of the int object `1`
- `allvars[0]`, which is where we thought we stored `a`, also gets the address of the int object `1`
- In `allvars[0] = allvars[0]+1`, the final `allvars[0]` gets the address of the resulting int object, `2`
- however, that doesn't change the fact that `a` still points to the int object `1`

The thing is, however, - I have a situation, where I have to manage a bunch of variables (like `a`, `b` ... above) separately; however, in the code, there are cases that would be more straightforward to handle, if I ran a loop over all these variables - but, the variables would *have* to be updated, because after the phase when the loops are useful, I have some remaining processing to be done on the variables (`a`, `b` etc) individually, where the updated values are expected.

So is there some (not too convoluted) way in Python, to put variables (or maybe, variable names) in a list/array, and then iterate over that array - and change the original variable (names)?

In terms of above example, I'd want to do something like this pseudocode:

```
...
for i, ix in enumerate(allvars):
  change_originals("allvars[i] = ix + 1")

print(a,b,c,d,e) # this should be 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Comment: Perhaps a dictionary like `{'a':1, 'b':2..}`will suffice?

Comment: Thanks, @DeveshKumarSingh  - I guess I might end up having to do that; but it would still be nice to know if there is (or isn't) a way to change the "original" variables that were stored in an array, by iterating over the array ...

Comment: But how many variables do you think you will end up storing and creating, That approach is not scalable. Also this happens since integer are immutable. Try this with say `a=[1000]` , which becomes a mutable list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of to do this would store the variable names as strings in a list, then use the `exec` function. This function always returns 0. It accepts a string argument and then executes that string as valid python code. So:

```
# Where allvars contains string names of variables
...
for i, ix in enumerate(allvars):
  exec(f"{allvars[i]} = {ix} + 1")
```

Another way would use the locals() function, which gives you a dictionary with names and values of variables and any other names:

```
# using locals() function
# Make a list of variable names
allvars_strings = ['a','b','c','d','e']
# Slightly simpler

for i in allvars_strings:
  locals()[i] = locals()[i] + 1

string = ''
print('\n\n')
for i in allvars_strings:
  string += str(locals()[i]) + ', '
print(string[:-2])
```

Comment: Many thaniks for that @Anon - both exec and locals are great tips!

Answer (score 2):

Here you have created an `array` of `primitives` value. `Primitives` always copy whenever you use it. So mofication wont reflect on the `original variable`.

There are possible solution base on your requirement.

```
class Val: 
    def __init__(self, val = -1): 
         self._val = val 
    def get_val(self): 
        return self._val 

    # setter method 
    def set_val(self, x): 
        self._val = x 

allvars = []
one = Val(1) 
allvars.append(one)
print(allvars[0]._val) 
one.set_val(2) 
print(allvars[0]._val)
```

1. You can use a dictionary with key[1,2,3,4...]
2. You can create array of object